# Computer keeps crashing after I replaced the RAM

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, crash

I have an early 2010 MacBook Pro. I just upgraded the RAM to 8GB because I was constantly using more than 4GB. I have upgraded to flash storage as well so I didn't want my system constantly using swap. My MacBook keeps crashing constantly. Here is my error log:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  26019 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    372A45EB-F401-8CF5-4375-11E86EC6A531

Sun Sep  1 16:57:38 2013
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80244b8655): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8024487ca3, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fa3e6003000, CR3: 0x000000000ba5f05f, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0e5000ffffff805a, RBX: 0xffffff8028da83a0, RCX: 0x0e5000ffffff805a, RDX: 0xffffff8024abdac0
RSP: 0xffffff8114be3ce0, RBP: 0xffffff8114be3d00, RSI: 0x000000002231db52, RDI: 0xffffff8027b4ea20
R8:  0xfffffffffffff000, R9:  0xffffff8039395580, R10: 0x0000000103b04000, R11: 0x0000000000000200
R12: 0x0000000000019440, R13: 0xffffff8028dbd958, R14: 0xffffff8027b4ea20, R15: 0xffffff8026b42000
RFL: 0x0000000000010207, RIP: 0xffffff8024487ca3, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007fa3e6003000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8114be3980 : 0xffffff802441d626 
0xffffff8114be39f0 : 0xffffff80244b8655 
0xffffff8114be3bc0 : 0xffffff80244ce17d 
0xffffff8114be3be0 : 0xffffff8024487ca3 
0xffffff8114be3d00 : 0xffffff80244893a8 
0xffffff8114be3d20 : 0xffffff80244894e8 
0xffffff8114be3d60 : 0xffffff802447c637 
0xffffff8114be3d90 : 0xffffff8024476524 
0xffffff8114be3dc0 : 0xffffff80244759b0 
0xffffff8114be3e00 : 0xffffff802446737c 
0xffffff8114be3ef0 : 0xffffff802446b0e0 
0xffffff8114be3f20 : 0xffffff80247b8c66 
0xffffff8114be3f50 : 0xffffff80247e16aa 
0xffffff8114be3fb0 : 0xffffff80244ce9c3 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: AppleIDAuthAgent

Mac OS version:
12E55

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 896CB1E3-AB79-3DF1-B595-549DFFDF3D36
Kernel slide:     0x0000000024200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8024400000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16155595033
last loaded kext at 5864370255: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60 (addr 0xffffff7fa56f1000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AGPM    100.12.87
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver    1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics    8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU    4.1.4f2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport    4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight    170.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC    1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl    1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver    237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    320.15
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver    3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache    34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    3.5.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter    404
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC    1.4.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331    615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.1b4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement    196.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport    4.1.4f2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController    1.0.11d0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    1.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily    1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily    2.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    530.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient    5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController    1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    5.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox    220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA, 0x202020202020202020202020202020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA, 0x202020202020202020202020202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.4f2 12041, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: INTEL SSDSC2CW180A3, 180.05 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Is my RAM defective? Should I just revert back to the original 4GB RAM?

---

Update:

I tested the RAM several times and I couldn't find the problem. I think that the RAM must have been bad near the beginning of the sequence so it was hard to find, but I'm not really sure. I just went to the store and bought new RAM and now my Mac never crashes. Thank you everyone for all of the help.

If you are having the same problem that I was having, just get new RAM, it is a lot less trouble and it will save you hours of testing your RAM (which is not fun).

Comment: Your RAM is fine, it is showing up correctly.

Comment: Just because the ram shows up correctly, doesn't mean the ram isn't bad! Run a memory test to know for sure. http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/

Comment: That is a useful test for those who can get they computer operational at all.

Comment: So is the RAM test a good idea?

Comment: Yes, it cant hurt -- not a bad idea anytime you install new ram.  After you fix  the authagent problem run a memtest like in the link above.  Let it do its thing and come back in a half hour and check if any errors came up.  Sometimes ram can be defective and most manufacturers will ship you a replacement right away if anything is wrong.

Comment: @spuder please put your comment as an answer so if it works I can accept it.

Comment: There is an official hardware test on the installation media (or in ROM).  Run that to see if everything is fine.

Comment: Wasting your time testing the new RAM. Simplest way is to reinsert the old RAM. If the machines runs fine, then you have ruled out that the new memory is faulty. It could be that your Mac doesn't like it (some models are notoriously finicky about memory) or that  it is indeed just a bad stick(s). In any case, it isn't working for you so I'm not sure there is much of a point trying to isolate exactly why. A hardware fault can't be "fixed."

Answer (score 1):

Your system identifies the RAM correctly:

> Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA,
>   0x202020202020202020202020202020202020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4
>   GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA, 0x202020202020202020202020202020202020

However, there is another problem with your

> AppleIDAuthAgent

Try fixing it with this:

1. Restart system in safe mode.
2. If that does not work restart in repair mode <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Once I have it in safe mode, then what do I do?

Comment: I think Buscar meant that just starting up in Safe Mode and then rebooting normally fixes the problem. However, Buscar should clarify.

Comment: I rebooted in safe mode and it was super slow, it took about 2 mins to boot when it usually only takes about 7 seconds. I logged in and waited a while and then rebooted. It hasn't crashed yet, I will accept this answer if it doesn't crash by tomorrow.

Comment: Restarting in Safe mode allows os to get sorted out in the start up sequence (on the shutdown). Yours got stuck on the AppleIDAuthAgent (a keychain passwords -reason unknown). As for the RAM test, now you can actually do that since your computer is up and running. :) Enjoy your 8 gig.

Comment: It crashed again today, i will try the RAM test.

Comment: Waiting for the results :)

Comment: Note that the crash may be due to the crashing program being placed in faulty RAM.  Safe mode uses memory differently and hence not trigger the same crash.

Comment: I did the RAM test about 3 or 4 times, it always says everything is good but my system keeps crashing once in a while. I don't think the RAM tester is testing the RAM where it is defective. I think that there might be some dead registers somewhere near the start of the RAM and it seems like the RAM tester only tests the available RAM. Any other ideas?

Comment: I almost said "I told you so" :)...your report shows a problem with the AppleIDAuthAgent!, but if you must run the Apple Hardware test just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons your Mac could crash.

To rule out memory, try running a memory test:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/

Additionally, you should double check that the ram you purchased runs at a supported latency. Use [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca) or go to the website of the ram manufacture for a list of tested computers.

If you put the old ram back and the crashing stops, then that is as close to a smoking gun as you will find.

If the Memory test passes and putting the old memory back in don't fix it, the next place to look would be a corrupted OS

Try:

- Repair permissions, verify disk
- Boot into safemode (hold shift key while booting up your mac)
- Disable all startup items and enable them a few at a time until the crashing returns
- Create a new user account
- If you have a spare hard drive, install a clean OS to it and boot from it temporarily.

Comment: I ran the RAM tester, it always says that my RAM is good but I don't think so. I think that there is a bad register somewhere near the beginning of the sequence, is there any way to use the RAM checker to check all of the RAM, not just the available RAM?